# Real analysis: find value of $k$ that makes $f$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have this home work problem

$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      K & x = 0 \\
      \frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(5x)} & x \neq 0\\
   \end{cases}$

Find the value of $k$ that makes $f(x)$ continuous at $0$

I tried using epsilon delta definition but it would not give me the value...my question is how to work this type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function $f(x)$ to be continuous, at a point $x = a$, the function must be defined at $a$, and the right-hand and left-hand limits must be equal to each other as $x$ approaches $a$.

Since the function $\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(5x)}$ has a right-hand limit and left-hand limit equal to $0$, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(5x)} = 0 $$

Thus, $k = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\sin 0}{\cos 0} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f$ is continuous at $0$ then $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=f(0)$$.